# Cannot add python3 kernel to Jupyter

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I wanted to change path of the kernel in Jupyter to set it to the one I'm using in the machine.

Here is the original  kernels that were install in jupyter:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

> Available kernels:
>   python3    /home/n/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
>   python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2

Then I checked the path of python3 in my machine like this:

```
which python3
```

> /usr/bin/python3

$ ipython kernelspec list

I deleted the kernel of python3 like this:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall python3
```

which was successfully performed, then I tried to install python3 using the path I found earlier like this:

> jupyter kernelspec install /usr/bin/python3

which gave me this error:

> File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-kernelspec", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(KernelSpecApp.launch_instance())
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 658, in launch_instance
>       app.start()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspecapp.py",
>   line 273, in start
>       return self.subapp.start()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspecapp.py",
>   line 143, in start
>       replace=self.replace,
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py",
>   line 299, in install_kernel_spec
>       shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
>
> names = os.listdir(src) OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/bin/python3'

Then I looked for the correct path like this:

```
python3 -c "import sys; print ('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

> /usr/lib/python3.4
>
> /usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
>
> /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.4.egg
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

I tried to install it gain like this:

```
sudo jupyter kernelspec install /usr/lib/python3.4
```

> [InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec python3.4 in
>   /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3.4

Now, when I start jupyter there is no Python 3 at all as a kernel, I'm not sure now what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling python3 using anaconda which comes with Jupyter included in its package.

You can install anaconda by follwoing the commands in here: 
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't installed `ipykernel` on your python 3 install. To install a python kernel the proper steps are:

`pip3 install ipykernel`

`python3 -m ipykernel install --user`

See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)

Comment: This did not solve the issue, by following this command I'm installing the version ipython provides not the one that's already installed on my machine. This causes errors since libraries that I already installed are not used in the notebook due to the different paths.